# What is the difference between named return value and normal return value?

Tags: go

My question is about the different named return value vs normal return value.

my code

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    f := fmt.Println
    f(a())
    f(b())
}

func a() int {
    i := 0
    defer func() {
        i += 1
        fmt.Println("a defer : ", i)
    }()

    return i
}

func b() (i int) {
    i = 0

    defer func() {
        i += 1
        fmt.Println("b defer : ", i)
    }()
    return i
}
```

the result:

**the a function return 0**

**the b function reutrn 1**

Why?

Comment: Why? By design. This feature allows a defered function to modify the values returned. Think of defer running _after_ return copied the values "back to the caller". For unnamed returns you modify a local variable; for named returns you return what got returned to the caller. So: By language spec. See https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The named return value also allocates a variable for the scope of your function.

`func a() int`: While you already return the value of `i = 0`, but since no named values was defined the static value got returned. So even though you're increasing `i` in the deferred function it doesn't affect the returned value.

`func b() (i int)`: The variable `i` is allocated (and already initialized to `0`). Even though the deferred function runs after the `i = 0` was returned the scope is still accessible and thus still can be changed.

---

Another point of view: you can still change named return values in deferred functions, but cannot change regular return values.

This especially holds true in the following example:

```
func c() (i int) {
    defer func() {
        i = 1
        fmt.Println("c defer : ", i)
    }()
    return 0
}
```

Comment: Defer runs before the return. Convince yourself by passing a pointer to `i` to the defer func.

Answer (score 4):

`defer` runs a function after the `return` statement but before the function is auctually returned, thus enabling modify returned results. However, only named return results can be accessed normally, i.e. by the variable name.

The `return` statement, when not naked (another thing about named return, but irrelevant here), the expression got evaluated. And if the return is named, the named variable is assigned with the evaluated value.

In your code, in `func a() int` the return is typed but not named. So when `return i` is execuated, it sets the return value, a variable not available to the code, as the value of `i`. You can consider it as `RETVAL := i`. And later, your deferred function modified `i` but the return value (`RETVAL`) remains unchanged.

But in `func b() (i int)`, i is a named return. Thus, when `return i` execuate, it literally translate to `i = i`. And later, your deffered function modified `i`, a return value, so the returned value change.

More on `return`: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Return_statements

Answer (score 0):

With the named return value you directly modify what gets returned, with the "normal" return value you just modify local variable in the scope of your function, which never gets returned.

More on this:

Deferred function can access named return values but it has no return value itself -  so this is actually the only way to modify main function results from there. Very useful thing.

Imagine you want to fix code which panics - you want it to return the error instead. You can solve it by using `recover` in a deferred function  and then assigning recovered error to named return value.

Example, somewhat abstract but hopefully useful:

```
func noMorePanics() (err error) {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            err = r.(error)
        }
    }()

    potentiallyPanickingFunction()
}
```